# Receive Private Message (in multiple browsers and with the same user id)

Tags: socket.io

I use socket.io and node.js.

How do I receive private messages, when I'll be logged in multiple browsers with the same ID?

I tried this problem and the message is read in the last open browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can emit specific socket id

```
io.sockets.socket(id).emit('a message', msg)
```